# Future of Mono & MonoDroid + MonoTouch?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've been evaluating MonoTouch and MonoDroid and think they look like great products.  I just saw an article that reports the Mono developers have been let go by Attachmate after their acquisition of Novell (http://blog.internetnews.com/skerner/2011/05/attachmate-lays-off-mono-emplo.html)  If this is true, what does it mean for the MonoTouch and MonoDroid tools?

Answer (score 4):

1. It doesn't say if they ALL were laid off...so lets not speculate.
2. I would learn MonoTouch anyways. It is a great way to become familiar with the Cocoa Touch libraries and the IPhone SDK. I feel like after working with MT for a year now, I can understand Objective-C code much easier and even write it when I need to.